# in indexedDB, is it possible to make an efficient equivalent of "where Column in (value1, value2.... value2)" call?

Tags: html, indexeddb

I want to implement this search using indexedDB:

```
where CustomerName in ('bob', 'fred'... 'nancy')
```

I can see two possibilities:

1) simply openCursor on object store, then loop through entire table, checking manually if a record is in ('bob', 'fred'... 'nancy')

2) using index, issue multiple calls to index openCursor('bob'), openCursor('fred')...

both openCursor take [IDBKeyRange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBKeyRange) which does not seem to allow searching for multiple, non continues  values

Is there another, more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would probably be to sort the keys you're searching for, open a cursor at the first one, `IDBCursor.continue` until you have all the values for that key and then `IDBCursor.advance` to the next key you're searching for. Repeat until you've done all the keys. That way you get all the values with only one cursor, but you can quickly skip over values you don't care about.

Answer (score 0):

Either of your suggestions work.

A performance improvement to #1 would be to first sort the list of keys (e.g. using `indexedDB.cmp()` to implement a comparison function), and open the cursor on the first key (e.g. 'bob'). Then, as you iterate, once you see key that's after 'bob' but before 'fred' you `continue('fred')` to skip the intervening records. This avoids iterating over the records in the table you don't care about.

The latest Chrome/Firefox/Safari also support getAll(), which would be a variant on your #2 to get all the records for a given key at once (e.g. via `getAll('nancy')`) rather than having to iterate a cursor.